# How to properly copy fields from derived classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance

let's take the following classes as an example:

**base class:**

```
public class Spell
{
    public int castRange;

    public Spell Copy()
    {
        Spell spell = new Spell();
        spell.castRange = this.castRange;
        return spell;
    }
}
```

**derived class:**

```
public class ManaSpell : Spell
{
    public int manaCost;

    public new ManaSpell Copy()
    {
        ManaSpell spell = new ManaSpell();
        spell.castRange = this.castRange;
        spell.manaCost = this.manaCost;
        return spell;
    }
}
```

I can't use *virtual* and *override* for the **Copy()** method because they have a different return types, so I use the *new* keyword. The problem starts with the next class:

```
public class Unit
{
    public Spell spell;

    public Unit(Spell spell)
    {
        // This will call the Copy method in the base class, even if the 
        // parameter is actually a ManaSpell

        this.spell = spell.Copy();

        // So instead I have to do a check first:

        if (spell is ManaSpell)
        {
            ManaSpell manaSpell = spell as ManaSpell;
            this.spell = manaSpell.Copy();
        }
    }
}
```

It all works, but it feels like a very inefficent design, especially if I add more and more classes derived from *Spell*, not to mention adding a field in the base class means changing the copy methods in all derived classes aswell.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should definitly read again about `new`, `virtual` and `override`. `new` is allmost allways a design-flaw. Anyway I don´t get your actual purpose. Why do you want top copy an instance of `ManaSpell` and reference it via a reference of type `Spell`. The latter doesn´t know anything of its derived types, so even if you *could* do what you want, `this.Spell`  will **allways** give you `Spell` as compile-time type.

Comment: Just omit the type-checking and the `new` and let the instance resolve which `Copy` to call itself.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but you should consider using [auto-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) instead of public fields. They provide better encapsulation, while fields aren't supported by default by some libraries/frameworks (WPF bindings, `Newtonsoft.Json`...). Using public fields are often considered as a bad practice by some so yeah :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a really good reason to **hide** (this is what `new` does) your `Copy`-implementation of the base-class, you shouldn´t `new` it.

It seems you won´t need that at all. You actually want to copy a `Spell`, no matter of its actual type. So let the instance resolve a call to `Copy`, which is done by usual overriding:

```
public class Spell
{
    public int castRange;

    public virtual Spell Copy()
    {
        Spell spell = new Spell();
        spell.castRange = this.castRange;
        return spell;
    }
}
public class ManaSpell : Spell
{
    public int manaCost;

    public override Spell Copy()
    {
        ManaSpell spell = new ManaSpell();
        spell.castRange = this.castRange;
        spell.manaCost = this.manaCost;
        return spell;
    }
}
```

Now you can call `Copy` on any instance of `Spell` without need to distinguish on the actual type:

```
this.Spell = spell.Copy()
```

this will resolve to a new instance of `Spell` if you have a base-class instance and to `ManaSpell` if you have an instance of the derived type.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to create clones is to use private method `MemberwiseClone` inherited from `System.Object`. It has the advantage to taking automatically into account fields from derived classes. I.e. you don't have to derive your copy method to make it work.

```
public class Spell
{
    public int castRange;

    public Spell ShallowClone()
    {
        return (Spell)MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"castRange = {castRange}";
}

public class ManaSpell : Spell
{
    public int manaCost;

    public override string ToString() => $"castRange = {castRange}, manaCost = {manaCost}";
}
```

This test ...

```
Spell spell = new ManaSpell { castRange = 5, manaCost = 10 };
var copy = spell.ShallowClone();
Console.WriteLine(copy);
Console.ReadKey();
```

... displays

> castRange = 5, manaCost = 10

You cannot avoid casting, if you need a result typed as `ManaSpell`.

---

A possible solution avoiding casting is to use a generic static method. The C# compiler can infer the return type from the static (compile time) parameter type.

```
public class Spell
{
    public int castRange;

    public Spell ShallowClone()
    {
        return (Spell)MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"castRange = {castRange}";

    public static T ShallowClone<T>(T original)
        where T : Spell
    {
        return (T)original.ShallowClone();
    }
}
```

This ...

```
ManaSpell manaSpell = new ManaSpell { castRange = 6, manaCost = 18 };
ManaSpell manaSpellCopy = Spell.ShallowClone(manaSpell);
Console.WriteLine(manaSpellCopy);
```

... prints

> castRange = 6, manaCost = 18